# Excluir un numero con pseudocodigo PSeInt

Tags: bucles, pseint, pseudocódigo

soy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo una duda. Tengo que meter numeros repetidamente y que salga por pantalla cual es el numero maximo que se ha introducido y cuantas veces se ha repetido, se termina de meter numeros cuando se introduce un 999. La duda es como excluyo el 999 para que no cuente para el maximo y solo actue como terminador del bucle. Gracias de antemano. Aquí el codigo.

Algoritmo EjercicioNueve

```
Definir maximo como entero
maximo = 0
repetidas = 0;
Repetir
    Escribir "Introduce un numero: "
    Leer numeroo
        Si numeroo > maximo Entonces
            maximo <- numeroo
            repetidas = repetidas+1

    FinSi
Hasta Que numeroo = 999


Imprimir "El número máximo es el " maximo
Imprimir "El número se ha repetido " repetidas "veces."
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: Lo primero que debe hacer es hacer una condicion que pregunte si la variable de teclado es 999 de ser cierto sale, en caso contrario se compara el numero de entrada por teclado con el numero maximo almacenado si esta es maximo se asigna ese a la variable maximo y pones el contador en uno. luego compara el numero de teclado si es igual a Maximo entonces incrementas el contado + 1

Comment: Excelente, no te olvides de calificar la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCION:**

Esta es la modificacion del pseudocodigo para que evalue la entrada del 999 y no la considere como un numero maximo, tambien se agrego otro if() para sumar al numero maximo y si este cambia se reinicia el contador para volver a sumar el nuevo numero maximo.

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
    Definir maximo como entero
    maximo = 0
    repetidas = 0;
    Repetir
        Escribir "Introduce un numero: "
        Leer numeroo
        // limita el acceso al numero 999
        Si numeroo <> 999 entonces
            // saber si se repite se cuenta
            si numeroo = maximo Entonces
                repetidas = repetidas+1
            FinSi
            // si el numeroo > se asigna y repetiva vuelve a contar
            Si numeroo > maximo Entonces
                maximo <- numeroo
                repetidas = 1
            FinSi
        FinSi

    Hasta Que numeroo = 999


    Imprimir "El número máximo es el " maximo
    Imprimir "El número se ha repetido " repetidas " veces."
FinAlgoritmo
```

Esta es la salida por pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que sea de ayuda...

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me ha servido :)

Comment: Excelente, no te olvides de calificar la respuesta